# get json array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi how to get json array elements in different ids in response?

//server side jsp

```
 <%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
<%
  JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();               
 JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
 obj.put("name","data");// how can i display string "name" in secondcombobox id?
 obj.put("roll_no","data"); how can i display string "roll_no" in thirdcombobox id?
 out.println(obj.toString());
%>
```

client side jsp where retrieving json array elements in javascript

```
 $("#firstcombo").change(function() {
 $.get('comboboxpage.jsp', { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, function(responseData) {
 $("#secondcomboboxid").replaceWith(data.name);// here i want to display name, how can i do it?
 $("#thirdcomboboxid").replaceWith(data.roll_no);// here i want to display roll no, how can i do it?
});
});

<input type="text" id="secondcomboboxid" name="secondcomboboxid"/>// how can i show name here?
<input type="text" id="thirdcomboboxid" name="thirdcomboboxid"/> how can i show roll_no here?
```

How can i display **name** in **secondcomboboxid** and **roll no** in **thirdcomboboxid**? I googled a lot but could not find any solution, Any ideas please

Comment: post the json you are getting in the response from the server

Comment: Please post the full string value of responseData so I can be sure of it's format.

Comment: @3nigma i am getting no response from server side, how should i modify JSON Array objects to get response in client side?

Comment: @SoonDead full string value of responseData means? If i am writing out.println("somevalue"); in server side then i am getting "somevalue" in secondcombobox id and also in thirdcombobox id, which i want to separate, how should i modify my client and server side code?

Comment: What does the network tab say in e.g., FireBug ?

Comment: @Josh have a look at me comments on Didier Ghys, if you can help how to modify server side JSON rray to retrieve value in javascript?

Comment: @tom what server side language you are using

Comment: @tom looks like you might need to call `.toString`, so `out.println(arrayObj.toString());` See: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: @3nigma it is a jsp page where i want to store values in JSON array as displayed in question, can you please tell me how should i edit JSON array so that i will get these two values in client side java script ids respectively?

Comment: @tom I also don't see add anywhere, docs have `put`. Can you give the full import statement?

Comment: @Josh please see my updated question, if possible please help me where should i edit server/client side code?

Comment: @3nigma please see my updated question, if possible please help me where should i edit server/client side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<%
          JSONObject arrayObj= new JSONObject();

           arrayObj.put("name","john");
           arrayObj.put("roll no","007");


          response.setContentType("application/json");
          response.getWriter().write(arrayObj.toString());

%>
```

client side

```
$.ajax({
url:'comboboxpage.jsp',
dataType:'json',
type:'GET',
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
},
error:function(jxhr){
console.log(jxhr.responseText);
}

});
```

here is a helpful [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json.html)

Comment: thanks 3nigma, but i am still getting no response, any idea? have you tested it in your terminal?

Comment: no i cant test it atm, see the answer update use `$.ajax` instead and make a error handler. are you sure the path to `comboboxpage.jsp` is correct, what does the firebug tells you, does it show status 200 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading JSON data, you'd better use the method [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) that will take care of parsing the response to a JSON object automatically.

Then you response data being an object, you can access its properties with the dot notation:
data.name.

Special case thought for the second property "roll no". As there is a white space, you would have to use the array notation to access the value: data['roll no'].

```
$.getJSON('comboboxpage.jsp', { combo1Val : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
    $("#secondcomboboxid").replaceWith(data.name);
    $("#thirdcomboboxid").replaceWith(data['roll_no']);
});
```

More generally, as mentionned by @diEcho, to parse a json string, you can use [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `data['roll no']` or is there some change caused by  `arrayObj.add()`?

Comment: thanks Didier for the answer but in server side JSON what modification should i do? i am getting no value in client side by on change event of first combo box.

Comment: I'm no familiar with JSP, but you can try following this [example](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples) (first part, not the ajax part)

Comment: I guess if you're sending a pure array, you're going to end up with `['name', 'roll no']` and you'll have to use data[0] and data[1] to access the values.

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name","data");
     obj.put("roll_no","data");
 out.println(obj);      like this?

Comment: This will output a JSON object of the form `{"name": "data", "roll no": "data" }` indeed for which you'll be able to access the properties as I describe.

Comment: but i am getting no data on client side, any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
responseData.name
responseDate.roll_no
```

or use [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: thanks diEcho for the answer but in server side JSON what modification should i do? i am getting no value in client side by on change event of first combo box.

Comment: I'm no familiar with JSP. but you must see the comment given by @Didier Ghys

Answer (score 1):

So, if I get your setup correctly, you're handling e.g., :8080 with some simple servlet and you want to give back JSON data via a jsp. I think this is not a great idea, but for prototyping, I suppose... Here's a possible *just make it work*:

```
<%  
    JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();                       
    arrayObj.put("name");
    arrayObj.put("roll no");
    out.println(arrayObj.toString());
%>
```

See above for the front-end components.

Comment: ok for receiving data i should follow  Didier Ghys's code right? but it is not displaying name/roll_no in second/third textbox, have a look at my updated question please